# how to solve this ODE of first order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am wondering how to solve 
$$ y=xy'- \sqrt{y'-1} $$

this one is giving me struggles solving it.
Any help or method very appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

$$y=xy'- \sqrt{y'-1}$$
$$y=xy'+f(y')$$
It's  [Clairaut 's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation).

Differentiate both sides.
$$xy''-\frac 12(y'-1)^{-1/2}y''=0$$
$$y''(x-\frac 12(y'-1)^{-1/2})=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: look for solutions of the form $y = a x + b$.